# Moving Rows from one sheet to another based on selected values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have an Apps Script I am using to move rows from one tab on my sheet to another based on what I select in a specific column.

The code I am using seems to work however it is putting two copies of the line on the second sheet I am pretty new to app script so i may have made an error in the code. I litterally just need the row to move over and delete from the original page.

```
function onEdit(e){
    var sourceSheet = e.range.getSheet();
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    if(sourceSheet.getSheetName() === 'Submissions'){
        var rowRange = sourceSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sourceSheet.getLastColumn());
        var rowValues = rowRange.getValues()[0];
        if(rowValues[16] === "Approved"){
            var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Completed");  
            targetSheet.appendRow(rowValues);  
            sourceSheet.deleteRow(row);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: those codes seems good to me.  If single action cause two copies of the new record. You might need to check your Triggers.  To see is there are duplicated trigger for same function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Delete Selected Rows

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
    if(sh.getName() == 'Submissions'){
        var rowRange = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn());
        var rowValues = rowRange.getValues()[0];
        if(rowValues[16] == "Approved"){
            var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Completed");  
            tsh.appendRow(rowValues);  
            sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
        }
    } 
}
```

Perhaps you create and installable trigger with the name onEdit.  In this case you are getting two triggers.  One the installable version and one from the simple trigger.  I also rewrote the function taking advantage of event object.